# Configuring Geoserver to use a proxy when accessing external services?

Tags: geoserver, proxy

I don't want to access my geoserver behind a proxy. I can access it directly. It is in same network as I with no proxy between us.

I have a Geoserver and created some layers consuming WMS services from somewhere.

My problem is that my geoserver is behind a proxy. its a governamental institution and all access to external world needs to authenticate do the proxy to go out. I need to configure it in my browser to use the internet, but need an exclusion rule in browser to access internal network (to ignore proxy).

I don't know how to tell Geoserver to login into that proxy to allow it access the outside WMS service I need to consume.

The result is as follow:

```
2016-05-02 10:03:59,749 ERROR [org.geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Internal error 
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:129)
    at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:320)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor300.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP error code 407 for URL http://mapas.icmbio.gov.br/i3geo/ogc.php?TEMA=uc_esec&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS
    at org.geotools.data.ows.MultithreadedHttpClient.get(MultithreadedHttpClient.java:202)
    at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.internalIssueRequest(AbstractOpenWebService.java:426)
    at org.geotools.data.wms.WebMapServer.issueRequest(WebMapServer.java:419)
    at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.negotiateVersion(AbstractOpenWebService.java:260)
    at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.<init>(AbstractOpenWebService.java:110)
    at org.geotools.data.wms.WebMapServer.<init>(WebMapServer.java:382)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getWebMapServer(ResourcePool.java:1653)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.WMSStoreInfoImpl.getWebMapServer(WMSStoreInfoImpl.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:146)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.getWebMapServer(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:464)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:248)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:119)
```

To go to `http://mapas.icmbio.gov.br/i3geo/ogc.php?TEMA=uc_esec&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS` it needs to login into same proxy I have configured in my browser (to go outside my network)

My proxy allow url auth like `<user>:<password>@<proxy_address>:<port>`

```
2016-05-02 10:03:53,627 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.ows] - Found 'http.proxyHost' Java System property. Using it as proxy server. Port: 6060
2016-05-02 10:03:53,627 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.ows] - Initialized with nonProxyHosts: [localhost, 10.5.115.122, 10.5.115.123, *.defesa.mil.br, 10.5.115.136, 10.5.115.110, 10.5.115.22, siglmd-app.defesa.mil.br]
2016-05-02 10:03:53,628 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.ows] - System property http.proxyUser and http.proxyPassword found, setting proxy auth credentials
2016-05-02 10:03:59,749 ERROR [org.geotools.data.ows] - Failed to execute request http://mapas.icmbio.gov.br/i3geo/ogc.php?TEMA=uc_esec&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS
2016-05-02 10:03:59,749 ERROR [org.geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Internal error 
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:129)
    at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:320)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor300.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
```

**EDIT:** Strange... some links are working others don't. This service gives me a `Server returned HTTP response code: 407 for URL`: `http://mapas.icmbio.gov.br/i3geo/ogc.php?tema=uc_esec&service=wms&request=getcapabilities` and this don't: `http://sigel.aneel.gov.br/arcgis/services/SIGEL/Distribuicao/MapServer/WMSServer`. I conclude it is not problem in my proxy since I can go outside in some cases...

Other cases: Work:

`http://sigel.aneel.gov.br/arcgis/services/SIGEL/Transmissao/MapServer/WMSServer?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities`

Don't work ( error 407 ):

`http://geoportal.lneg.pt/arcgis/services/RecursosHidro/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&version=1.1.0`

Geoserver proxy auth implementaion problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113341/http-407-proxy-authentication-required-how-to-handle-in-java-code

**EDIT**

This must be corrected to accept a password and an user name:
[image]

Still receiving `Internal error : Server returned HTTP error code 407 for URL http://XYZ/?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&amp;VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS` because it is ignoring username and password from `-Dxxx` configuration.

Comment: Are you running GeoServer on Jetty or Tomcat?

Comment: BTW. When you will get your way through the proxy you will probably find that you can't cascade layers from that service. It is MapServer and GeoServer has a problem with a combination of MapServer and WMS 1.3.0. Use WMS 1.1.1 or 1.1.0 instead.

Comment: I'll check this and put here. I'm not sure now. I'm using the bundle (embedded) version.

Comment: WMS 1.1.1 or 1.1.0 not worked.

Comment: As I said, you must first solve the problem with proxy authentication. You will face the problem with WMS 1.3.0 only after that because GeoServer can't resolve `request=GetSchemaExtension`that comes with the GetCapabilities.

Comment: Do you know why some links works and some others gives auth error? See my edit.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have own experience only from some experiments with Jetty and a non-authenticated proxy. That worked well for me.

Comment: Given your other question about osmosis proxying (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203905/how-to-setting-proxy-for-osmosis) , I think the problem is somewhere between your java and your proxy config. Trying to fix it above that is unlikely to be workable.

Comment: @BradHards I'm sure my Java proxy config is ok. I'm a Java developer and can make my own tests by downloading files outside my proxy and so on. The problem is in my proxy nature (I can't tell for sure because is a military organization and have a very, very limited access). I can tell you this solve the problem by changing the auth method in the java code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183277/http-error-407-proxy-authentication-required (Rohit Dodle answer). So I think `osmosis` and `Geoserver` is not considering my specific proxy nature and being more generic.

Comment: This question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183277/http-error-407-proxy-authentication-required) is EXACTLY what is happening with `osmosis` and `Geoserver`. The developers must review the connection method code. Errata: `solve the problem` above is not THIS problem, just my own test code connection problem (what the Geoserver guys must do).

Comment: If you feel this is a bug with the GeoServer code - please make a bug report at https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOS make sure you read and understand https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOS/summary first though

Comment: @IanTurton already done: `GEOS-9313`. Looking to the time I'm stuck with this simple option we don't have in Geoserver I just thinking in move to other tool to do it. Geoserver is very good but I can't wait for this solution to be build. I need an option to configure the proxy in the GUI. Almost all products have this option and it is even intuitive to developers. But in Geoserver we just can't use an authenticated proxy.

Comment: please see http://geoserver.org/support/ if you need more speed and are unable to make the changes yourself

Comment: Admin login ---> Global --> 4th input field is: 'Proxy Base URL'.
Enter your proxy sever and you're done.
It  kills your 'Layer Preview' though as the proxy doesn't know about Openlayers.
source: https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/message/31231303/

Comment: @Predator X This is not what I need. I need to create a WMS store in my Geoserver that come from a Geoserver that is outside my proxy and I need to authenticate to it to go outside using my username and password. I don't need to provide a proxy base url to my layer.

Comment: hmm, I think you want connect to geoserver that only access via proxy moreover you can surf the Internet your browser at the same time? yes or not? if yes I think this issue is not relate to geoserver or wms, I think you should be able define exception in your browser, the browser must be able automatically switch to proxy when you want get access to geoserver through wms service. I'm not sure I didn't test but I think this is available in chrome proxy settings, you can define exceptions read this link also: set chrome proxy for specific IP and websites

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-configure-Chrome-browser-to-use-a-proxy-only-when-connecting-to-certain-IP-addresses-and-websites

Comment: Does your nonProxyHost parameter overlap with your proxyHost parameter? mait* and maitproxy?

Comment: `I think you want connect to geoserver that only access via proxy moreover you can surf the Internet your browser at the same time?` : NO. I just want to access only my own geoserver. And my own geoserver have a `WMS Store` pointing to a WMS layer from another geoserver outside my network. To my own geoserver reach the other geoserver owner of the layer I want outside my network it needs to pass thru my proxy. To pass thru my proxy it needs to use my own proxy user credentials that will need a password. And the Geoserver guys forgotten to consider this and it only uses host/port.

Comment: Why do I need all this stuff? Why don't I use directly the geoserver owner of the layer I want? Because I REALY need to use that layer in an offline environment. So I think I could cache all the layer with me and say bye to the layer's owner.

Comment: The problem is not my browser. I'm only accessing my own geoserver inside my network and behind my proxy. Who need to pass thru the proxy is my geoserver not me.

Comment: Are you sure that you have a right address? https://mapas.icmbio.gov.br/i3geo/ogc.php?TEMA=uc_esec&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS gives `The requested URL /i3geo/ogc.php was not found on this server` for me.

Comment: @user30184 yes. I'm not using this address anymore. The FACT is my internal geoserver can't use ANY external (outside my proxy) WMS layer as Store. ANY ONE. At my home without proxy all works very fine. To reproduce my problem just create a new WMS Cascade Store pointing to a WMS server provider outiside a proxy that needs an user/password authentication. It won't work.

Comment: Well, I have done that but it was some time ago. I will try it again later.

Comment: Only if your proxy is basic type without authentication. If you have a corporate proxy that require user/password it won't work. Geoserver don't knows how to handle secured proxy. An ordinary proxy will work fine using the `-Dhttpxxxxx` tomcat JAVA_OPTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that is impossible to do it for now until geoserver give us a way to use secured proxy.

The definitive solution is to use MapProxy to cascade WMS layers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the http proxy variables either using a system environment variable or through a JVM property set in catalina.sh. There are detailed steps on how to do this on the [WFS Store page.](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/wfs.html)

In the past there have been issues with the HTTP COnnection pooling not picking up the proxy variables so if it continues to not work try unclicking the connection pooling box.

[image]

Comment: Documentation: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/wfs.html. Read about "Connecting to an external WFS layer via a proxy server".

Comment: Thanks. But still getting `error code 407`. Please see my edit 2.

Comment: I've also exported http_proxy and a wget from command line (in geoserver machine) worked fine. Seems a geoserver problem.

Comment: Try unclicking connection pooling in the store page

Comment: What version? there is no connection pooling in store page. Just HTTP connection manager, and a user and password boxes.

Comment: Connection pooling not solved. I'm already set proxy variables in startup.sh as you can see in my last error log. See my EDIT to more important information.

Comment: @user30184 already read this. Passing user/password in `-Dhttpxxx` parameter is useless.

Comment: Ok, Proxy with user/password is something that I have not tried. I suggest you to try a proxy that does not require credentials and see if you can get through that. Perhaps this https://memorynotfound.com/configure-http-proxy-settings-java/ is useful.

Comment: This may also be an issue in Jetty https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/381 fixed for version 9.3. GeoServer comes with something older I believe.