# How to setting proxy for osmosis?

Tags: osmosis

I'm trying to use osmosis to update my data ( http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Minutely_Mapnik ) but I'm facing the follow error:

```
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Unable to read the state from the server.
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.replication.common.ServerStateReader.getServerState(ServerStateReader.java:116)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.replication.common.ServerStateReader.getServerState(ServerStateReader.java:50)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.replication.v0_6.BaseReplicationDownloader.runImpl(BaseReplicationDownloader.java:290)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.replication.v0_6.BaseReplicationDownloader.run(BaseReplicationDownloader.java:383)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 407 for URL: http://planet.openstreetmap.org/replication/hour/state.txt
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.replication.common.ServerStateReader.getServerState(ServerStateReader.java:97)
        ... 4 more

jul 28, 2016 8:26:55 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis main
GRAVE: Execution aborted.
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: One or more tasks failed.
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.waitForCompletion(Pipeline.java:146)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.run(Osmosis.java:92)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.main(Osmosis.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

I'm already done `export JAVACMD_OPTIONS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=MY_PROXY -Dhttp.proxyPort=6060 -Dhttp.proxyUser=MY_USER-Dhttp.proxyPassword=MY_PASSWORD"` but with no success. I'm able to access this URL using the browser.

I know... `407` is for Authentication. The setting I'm using is correct for sure or my browser will give same error.

One more information: as seen in ([How to configure Geoserver to use a proxy when accessing external services?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191959/how-to-configure-geoserver-to-use-a-proxy-when-accessing-external-services)) I'm facing same problem in Geoserver. SOME external WMS services gives me same `407` error, others don't.

I think this is because of proxy auth implementation inside the code (osmosis and geoserver may be using same method): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183277/http-error-407-proxy-authentication-required

Comment: in your export command, there is a missing space between the proxyUser and proxyPassword parts. Unlikely its the real issue, but always good to check the simplest things first. Otherwise, it looks like a problem with your config and something in java (i.e. not a geoserver or osmosis problem, although they expose the same real issue).

Comment: @BradHards I double checked. It is just a typo here.

Comment: As said in other post, It is not a Java proxy config problem in my environment. I created a little Java program to download some file from internet thru my proxy and some methods causes same problem while the `Authenticator` solution seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113341/http-407-proxy-authentication-required-how-to-handle-in-java-code and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183277/http-error-407-proxy-authentication-required solved the problem. I think `osmosis` guys must check the code to use the `Authenticator`.

Comment: As said in my other post too, my proxy have a very strict nature allowing just `HTTP` and `HTTPS` ( no `SOCKS`, ports and etc ).

Comment: I think you need to provide a detailed bug report on the applicable bug tracker(s).